# Windows Service starting properly but not executing a code

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I am writing to you with a problem I have encountered:
After installation of Windows Service without any problems I started my own Windows Service (from Release), everything looked good but any of my codes were executed. What is more I would like to emphasize that after running the same code directly from Visual Studio, everything went fine.
If anyone knows how to solve this problem, please let me know.

Comment: any specific error traced ?

Comment: Do you see anything in your logs (you _do_ have logging, right?), or in the event log?

Comment: Event logs must have some clue if service is crashing

Comment: Hey, thank you for your quick answers. I have nlog but i did not notice any errors in my datebase. Could this be an authorization problem because today I added an app.manifest to enable and disable the service from webapi.

Comment: running a Windows Service project in the debugger causes a different startup entry point of the executable to be used, as compared to hosting it in the service environment. Add logging to OnStart. Does the service control manager show it as "started" or does it indicate "stopped" again shorty after you send it the start command?

Comment: Cee McSharpface, i will try to do that today evening or tomorrow morning. If i get any response i will message to you in this comment or in private message. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please post your code so we can see how your service is built. Otherwise we are stabbing in the dark.

Comment: Cee McSharpface service is running automatically.